# Facebook Like Box cached

Tags: php, facebook

Is there a reason I should not load this content with a cronjob running every hour and linking the like to the facebook page itself instead of loading everything from facebook?

Maybe including further optimizations like joining everyone's photo into a single one?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/

Comment: If you cache it, it won't be under the context of the user accessing it. (ie the user logged into Facebook accessing it with their credentials/cookies)

Comment: In that case, loading on the fly the like button alone would do most of it, I think, and still reduce load times....

Comment: The good thing is there is no traffic against your web server, since all the requests are going to the facebook domain directly from the client.